# Database login doesn't seem to be working when password is correct

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

In the following code I check a username and password with a database and then run an if statement to either allow the user to view the page or just show them a "Please login" message. At this point it is only returning the false values even if the passwords are equal.

I know I can pick up code for this on the internet, but I want to figure out where my logic (only in my head) is going wrong. I also know I haven't sanitized the data, but this is just a tutorial for grade 10 students just learning HTML and CSS with a little bit of PHP. I will get to that protecting data later - one concept at a time.

Thanks for the help!

```
<?php

// connects to server 

include('includes/connect2.php');

// sets post to variables don't know if this is needed
$user=$_POST[username];
$pass=$_POST[password];

?>

<?php
// query to find ifnoramtion in database 
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM social_register WHERE Login='$user'"); 
                    mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user) . "'" ); 

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($pass == $row['Password']) { ?>
<div id="container">
    <div id="banner">
    The social Site 
        <div id="site_logo">
        <img src="images/logo_thumb.gif" /> 
                <?php

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                  {
                  echo $row['First_Name'] . " " . $row['Last_Name'];
                  echo "<br>";
                    }
                mysqli_close($con);
                ?>

        </div>
    </div>

<div id="person">
<h1>Welcome to your test web site</h1>
</div>


</div>
<?php
}
else 
{
?>
    <div id="container">
            <div id="banner">
            The social Site 
                <div id="site_logo">
                <img src="images/logo_thumb.gif" /> 


                </div>
            </div>

        <div id="person">
        <h1>You have not loged into the site, please login.</h1>
        </div>

<?php
}

?>
```

Comment: My login is `foo' OR 1=1--` ;)

Comment: There's quite a lot wrong here, quite aside from whatever bug you are immediately experiencing. SQL injection vulnerability and passwords stored in plain text are two I'd fix immediately.

Comment: I agree that I need to look at the SQL and password problem, but as I said this is for teaching very basic PHP to grade 10 students who really need to do one concept at a time. Once we get the code to run, then we can work to fix the security problems.(this is never going to outside net) Other than those problems any fundamental problems with how I wrote it or my logic?

Comment: Well, I have put you some code more than before...

Comment: OK, sorry - I was speed-reading. Try echoing out `$pass` and `result['Password']`, and let us know what they both contain.

Comment: Yeah so I am not getting the $result['Password'] variable.

Comment: "but this is just a tutorial for grade 10 students just learning HTML and CSS with a little bit of PHP"

Teaching insecure code and then how to secure it is the wrong approach. Use parameterised queries in the first place.

Comment: Also this is clearly homework help, you're not the teacher....

Comment: Also, `$user=$_POST[username]` will raise a warning. Turn on warnings if you haven't already, and quote your array string indexes (so that should be `$user=$_POST['username']`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should fetch data with `mysqli_fetch_assoc` before match `password`

```
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user);
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM social_register WHERE Login = '".$user."'"); 

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($pass == $row['Password']) { ?>
```

Comment: Edited to use `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: I have tried this, but still returns else part of the statement, and I know that the variables are echo(ing) out database results so I must have made a mistake somewhere else? Possibly?

Comment: Please `var_dump()` after `fetch assoc` like this: `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); var_dump($row);` what you get?

Comment: @Vincent - Bora's code is correct, even if it is not your only problem. It might help to update your question with your amended code, so that readers can see the current state of your situation.

Comment: is the Login='" missing Login='$user'" or am I missing a fundamental idea here?

Comment: @Vincent you use `mysqli_real_escape_string` wrong. Updated codes.

Comment: Did you dump `row`? May be your query return `null`. Check it first

Comment: I just updated the code and same result with no echoing $result['Password'] humm

Comment: no `$result['Password']`. It's `$row['Password']`. Just `var_dump($row);` and show results

Comment: so the problem has to be with the $row['Password'] part if I change this to an actual value like "mypass" it return the true part of the page. Does that help?

Comment: Probably your query return `NULL`. Just check your query and result

Comment: so I did print $result; and received nothing so I might have to start from scratch again.

Comment: no `$result`. You have to dump `$row` like: `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); var_dump($row);` if you get `NULL` your query is wrong.

Comment: Yeah I am getting NULL so at least I know where the mistake is thanks

Comment: Can I ask you what does the var_dump($row) do? other than the obvious dump the result of the variable? Why would this not always give you NULL?

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I found my mistake, it was with the connection, I was sure it was connecting to the database, but in the end there was a mistake somewhere in that code. You suggestion worked like a charm.

Answer (score -2):

Well, I have put you an Login.php, and a Check.php, I hope that you enjoy it... :P

Try that:

```
//Login.php
session_start(); //create the session
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{

$con = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM social_register WHERE Login='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user) . "'" )); 

$pass = $user['Password']; //put the pass variable
if ( $pass == $user['Password'] ) {
    $_SESSION['ready'] = true;
    header('Location: you_page.php'); //redirect to your page when you have the correct pass
    exit;
} else
{
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
alert('Incorrect Password')
//-->
</script>
<?php
}
}
//continue with the next block
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title> Login </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h3 style="color:#fff;">Password:<h3>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="password" style="text-align:center;" name="pass"><br>
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Iniciar sesión">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>

//Check.php
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['ready'])
    || $_SESSION['ready'] !== true) {
    header('Location: login.php'); //Redirect to the login if you haven't the session set
    exit;
}
?>
```

In your_page.php, you have to put:

```
require 'check.php';
```

Logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['ready'])) {
   unset($_SESSION['ready']);
}
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: I've not downvoted, but I would recommend you deal with the SQL injection in the OP's question. Helping with a login form is a minor detail if you solution doesn't avoid them getting hacked `;-)`.

Comment: Thanks for vote me down whoever wants... ¬¬